# Remove cart quantity from custom options

Tags: php, magento, magento2.1

I am using magento 2.1.6

Have 1 issue in custom options it is behaving wearied when i update quantity from cart page.

**Example:** When i update cart item quantity from 1 to 3 than in items custom options it is showing `Custom Option: 3 x test`

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEaEa.png)

I want to get rid from that `3 x`.

**NOTE:** No extensions were used, its just a default fresh setup

Looking For help

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I want to remove the quantity in minicart.